# JavaScript npm install Heroku, Refrence Error Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

```js
document.getElementById("HC").innerHTML = String(hammingCode.encode("11"));


console.log("Encode 1111: ", hammingCode.encode("1111"));
```

I am trying to use [This](https://npm.runkit.com/hamming-code) hamming code npm libary in my JavaScript code, however i dont have much experience with installing from npm.
I have done npm install hamming-code and it managed to install i believe, my package.json has also updated with "hamming-code": "0.0.2".
When i begin to type hammingCo... it comes up with the examples, encode and decode etc, however when i try to encode a simple string, i get the console error message 'Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: hammingCode is not defined'. The app is deployed via heroku.

Do i need to add any additional source, or include 'var hammingCode = require("hamming-code")'? I have tried to include this, but am still unable to get it working.

I have an index.html where most of my JavaScript is and where i would like to use the hamming code, and an index.js where i believe most of my server code is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code the is having this problem

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the hamming-code script in your html file. For example check below example.

```js
/**
 * hammingEncode - encode binary string input with hamming algorithm
 * @param {String} input - binary string, '10101'
 * @returns {String} - encoded binary string
 */
function hammingEncode(input) {
 if (typeof input !== 'string' || input.match(/[^10]/)) {
  return console.error('hamming-code error: input should be binary string, for example "101010"');
 }

 var output = input;
 var controlBitsIndexes = [];
 var controlBits = [];
 var l = input.length;
 var i = 1;
 var key, j, arr, temp, check;

 while (l / i >= 1) {
  controlBitsIndexes.push(i);
  i *= 2;
 }

 for (j = 0; j < controlBitsIndexes.length; j++) {
  key = controlBitsIndexes[j];
  arr = output.slice(key - 1).split('');
  temp = chunk(arr, key);
  check = (temp.reduce(function (prev, next, index) {
   if (!(index % 2)) {
    prev = prev.concat(next);
   }
   return prev;
  }, []).reduce(function (prev, next) { return +prev + +next }, 0) % 2) ? 1 : 0;
  output = output.slice(0, key - 1) + check + output.slice(key - 1);
  if (j + 1 === controlBitsIndexes.length && output.length / (key * 2) >= 1) {
   controlBitsIndexes.push(key * 2);
  }
 }

 return output;
}


/**
 * hammingPureDecode - just removes from input parity check bits
 * @param {String} input - binary string, '10101'
 * @returns {String} - decoded binary string
 */
function hammingPureDecode(input) {
 if (typeof input !== 'string' || input.match(/[^10]/)) {
  return console.error('hamming-code error: input should be binary string, for example "101010"');
 }

 var controlBitsIndexes = [];
 var l = input.length;
 var originCode = input;
 var hasError = false;
 var inputFixed, i;
 
 i = 1;
 while (l / i >= 1) {
  controlBitsIndexes.push(i);
  i *= 2;
 }

 controlBitsIndexes.forEach(function (key, index) {
  originCode = originCode.substring(0, key - 1 - index) + originCode.substring(key - index);
 });

 return originCode;
}

/**
 * hammingDecode - decodes encoded binary string, also try to correct errors
 * @param {String} input - binary string, '10101'
 * @returns {String} - decoded binary string
 */
function hammingDecode(input) {
 if (typeof input !== 'string' || input.match(/[^10]/)) {
  return console.error('hamming-code error: input should be binary string, for example "101010"');
 }

 var controlBitsIndexes = [];
 var sum = 0;
 var l = input.length;
 var i = 1;
 var output = hammingPureDecode(input);
 var inputFixed = hammingEncode(output);


 while (l / i >= 1) {
  controlBitsIndexes.push(i);
  i *= 2;
 }

 controlBitsIndexes.forEach(function (i) {
  if (input[i] !== inputFixed[i]) {
   sum += i;
  }
 });

 if (sum) {
  output[sum - 1] === '1' 
   ? output = replaceCharacterAt(output, sum - 1, '0')
   : output = replaceCharacterAt(output, sum - 1, '1');
 }
 return output;
}

/**
 * hammingCheck - check if encoded binary string has errors, returns true if contains error
 * @param {String} input - binary string, '10101'
 * @returns {Boolean} - hasError
 */
function hammingCheck(input) {
 if (typeof input !== 'string' || input.match(/[^10]/)) {
  return console.error('hamming-code error: input should be binary string, for example "101010"');
 }

 var inputFixed = hammingEncode(hammingPureDecode(input));

 return hasError = !(inputFixed === input);
}

/**
 * replaceCharacterAt - replace character at index
 * @param {String} str - string
 * @param {Number} index - index
 * @param {String} character - character 
 * @returns {String} - string
 */
function replaceCharacterAt(str, index, character) {
  return str.substr(0, index) + character + str.substr(index+character.length);
}

/**
 * chunk - split array into chunks
 * @param {Array} arr - array
 * @param {Number} size - chunk size
 * @returns {Array} - chunked array
 */
function chunk(arr, size) {
 var chunks = [],
 i = 0,
 n = arr.length;
 while (i < n) {
  chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += size));
 }
 return chunks;
}

/* 
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD.
        define(factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
        // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
        // like Node.
        module.exports = factory();
    } else {
        // Browser globals (root is window)
        root.hammingCode = factory();
    }
}(this, function () {
    return {
      encode: hammingEncode,
      pureDecode: hammingPureDecode,
      decode: hammingDecode,
      check: hammingCheck
    };
})); */


console.log();
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML  =
hammingEncode('101010101');
```

```html
<div id="code">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code example is a bit poor, I'm guessing you are working in a javascript loaded by a webpage (based on the "document.getElementById...")

Make sure you are loading the script in your html, I suggest you do it in the  tag, be sure to load the library before your js and unless you are using a bundling tool like webpack, I doubt using require will work otherwise.

Hope it helps, if it doesn't please give us more info to help you.

Comment: yes sorry, there is little else that is relevant i believe. Thanks, kinda stupid question but you do know what it is i have to reference, or is it simply the url i linked?

Comment: What do you mean by reference? like how to load the library?

Comment: Yes, i assumed you meant something like '<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>' which is what I have done for socket.io library? or how would I load it, thanks.

Comment: yeah exactly, that's what I meant, you load the library with the location of the script and that should be enough for it to work, just be sure you load the library first and then your javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your file in client, don't have object `hammingCode`
Are you try add to your html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/georgelviv/hamming-code/master/index.js"></script>
```

My recommendation is download [hamming-code](https://cdn.rawgit.com/georgelviv/hamming-code/master/index.js) to your server and include it from html